# How to go about using form validation with using just javascript and DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Was given a puzzle to figure out which is to use just form validation using only js and the peculiar thing here is that there is no form name, and the types dont use IDs but they do have names, but the main objective besides that is to make sure at least there is some data entered on each input type (ie. fullname can even be 1 letter, as long as its one character).  Another thing to note is I cannot change the html code in anyway.  Since I cannot use form name in my validation, the examples I have seen online are helpful but not enough to the point where I can proceed.  Any help will be appreciated.

```
<form action = "form.html" method = "get"><br/>
Name:<input type = "text" name = "fullname" value="Enter Full Name"/><br/>
Gender:<br/>
Male<input type = "radio" name = "gender" value="male"/>Female<input type = "radio" name = "gender" 
value="female"/><br/>
Hobbies<br/>
Baseball <input type = "checkbox" name = "hobbies[]" value = "baseball" />  
Football <input type = "checkbox" name = "hobbies[]" value = "football" />  
Hockey <input type = "checkbox" name = "hobbies[]" value = "hockey" /><br/>
Favorite Show <select name = "show">
<option value = "">Choose Below</option>
<option value = "ATHF">Aqua Teen Hunger Force</option>
<option value = "Family Guy">Family Guy</option>
<option value = "Simpsons">Simpsons</option>
</select><br/>
Comments<br/>
<textarea cols = "50" rows = "6" name = "comments">Enter Comments</textarea><br/>
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "enter me" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bit messy but its working . I dont change any HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">

</style>

</head>
<body>
<form action = "form.html" method = "get"><br/>
Name:<input type = "text" name = "fullname" value="Enter Full Name"/><br/>
Gender:<br/>
Male<input type = "radio" name = "gender" value="male"/>Female<input type = "radio" name = "gender" 
value="female"/><br/>
Hobbies<br/>
Baseball <input type = "checkbox" name = "hobbies[]" value = "baseball" />  
Football <input type = "checkbox" name = "hobbies[]" value = "football" />  
Hockey <input type = "checkbox" name = "hobbies[]" value = "hockey" /><br/>
Favorite Show <select name = "show">
<option value = "">Choose Below</option>
<option value = "ATHF">Aqua Teen Hunger Force</option>
<option value = "Family Guy">Family Guy</option>
<option value = "Simpsons">Simpsons</option>
</select><br/>
Comments<br/>
<textarea cols = "50" rows = "6" name = "comments">Enter Comments</textarea><br/>
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "enter me" />
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(){
    name = document.getElementsByName("fullname")[0].value.length
    gender1 = document.getElementsByName("gender")[0].checked
    gender2 = document.getElementsByName("gender")[1].checked
    hobbies1 = document.getElementsByName("hobbies[]")[0].checked
    hobbies2 = document.getElementsByName("hobbies[]")[1].checked
    hobbies3 = document.getElementsByName("hobbies[]")[2].checked
    show = document.getElementsByName("show")[0].value
    comment = document.getElementsByName("comments")[0].value.length
    if(name==0 || (!gender1 && !gender2) || (!hobbies1 && !hobbies2 && !hobbies3) || comment==0 || show==""){
        alert("please fill all")
    }
}

button = document.getElementsByName("submit")
eButton = button[0].addEventListener("click",validate)
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: - Thanks for the help.  Question why does the pop up only work the first time?  In other words, if I forget to fill in 2 more fields, and say I just fill in one but hit the submit button again there is no pop up?  Would that mean I would have to put the button outside of the form?

Comment: Maybe because the the type of button on the end is submit? Try changing it "button"